# Can be table prefix in Doctrine changed without data loss?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, listener

I am trying to create `TablePrefixEventListener` from [medium.com](https://medium.com/@kcmueller/symfony-how-to-add-table-prefixes-with-doctrine-c7feff6ab95). Everything works almost perfectly. Generated migration contains `DROP TABLE` and `CREATE TABLE`.

Now the model situation is this: The web project is set and everything works for let's say a year. Many data are in the table. For a reason there will be decision to change the prefixes. Is there a way how to explain to the Listener that it should first create the table, migrate the data and then drop the old table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is a year from my question, I found a bit more how this works and the answer is in understanding how doctrine works.

It will not automatically do the rename table with `RENAME TABLE old TO new`, because the class metadata are changed in an EventListener. The Listener only changes the data and the following processes will see that the old table is gone and there is a new one.

But there is a silver lining. The generated migration can be edited before run. Those sql for `DROP` and `CREATE` can be manually deleted and `RENAME` statement can be added. Once the migration is run, the schema of the database will change and it will be in sync with doctrine metadata after firing loadClassMetada event, therefore it will see that everything is fine.